# Delete header/column from .txt file with bash

Tags: bash, replace

I'm automating a workflow with a bash script on Mac OSX. In this workflow, I'd like to add a command that deletes a header from my table (.txt) file that is tab delimited. It looks as follows:

```
header1 header2 header3
a       1       
b       2       
c       3       
d       4       
e       5       
f       6
```

As you can see, the third column, named `header3`, is empty.

I've noted [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130502/delete-columns-in-text-files-with-specific-string) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558748/delete-columns-from-space-delimited-file-where-file-header-matches) but I don't understand the arguments.

Could you suggest a line of code that automatically deletes the third column, or (even better) deletes the header called 'header3'?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x23170.html) in Table 2C.

```
sed s/header3//g input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: This is not deleting the third column, as requested in the question. You're deleting the word "header3" and nothing more. (If your file always has no values in the third column that, will be sufficient.) The `g` option performs a global delete, which is not necessary here, and calling `sed -i''` will edit the file in place without need for redirection.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is designed to work with whitespace-separated text columns:

```
awk '{print $1 "\t" $2}' input.txt > output.txt
```